# Copying a Directory and All of Its Contents - Java - Netbeans

Tags: java, file, netbeans, recursion, copy

My goal is to write a Java program in Netbeans to copy a directory and all of its contents, including subdirectories and their contents. To do so, I first ask the user for source directory and destination where it will be copied. From here, my program should make a new directory in the new location with same name as the source directory. Then my program should create an array with File class objects for each item in the contents of the source directory. Next, I tried to iterate the array, and for each item - if it is a file, it should copy to the new directory- if it is a directory, it should recursively call this method to the copy the directory and all of its contents.

An extremely useful program if I could just get it to work correctly. It is difficult for me right now to understand the entire logic needed to make this program run efficiently.

When I run the program, it returns that the file cannot be found but this is just not true. So my code has to be wrong somewhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated guys.

Thank you.

```
 package copydirectories;

 /**
 * CSCI 112, Ch. 18 Ex. 5
 * @author zhughes3
 * Last edited Tuesday, March 11th, 2014 @ 9pm
 */

 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class CopyDirectories {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //Create a new instance of scanner to get user input
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

    //Ask user to input the directory to be copied
    System.out.print("Input directory to be copied.");

    //Save input as String
    String dirName = scanner.nextLine();

    //Ask user to input destination where direction will be copied
    System.out.print("Input destination directory will be moved to.");

    //Save input as String
    String destName = scanner.nextLine();

    //Run method to determine if it is a directory or file
    isDirFile(dirName, destName);


}//end main

public static void isDirFile (String source, String dest) throws Exception{
    //Create a File object for new directory in new location with same name
    //as source directory
    File dirFile = new File (dest + source);

    //Make the new directory
    dirFile.mkdir();

    //Create an array of File class objects for each item in the source
    //directory
    File[] entries; 

    //If source directory exists
    if (dirFile.exists()){
        //If the source directory is a directory
        if (dirFile.isDirectory()){

            //Get the data and load the array
            entries = dirFile.listFiles();

            //Iterate the array using alternate for statement
            for (File entry : entries){
                if (entry.isFile()){
                    copyFile (entry.getAbsolutePath(), dest);
                } //end if
                else {
                    isDirFile (entry.getAbsolutePath(), dest);
                }  //end else if
            }//end for
        }//end if
    }//end if
    else {
        System.out.println("File does not exist.");
    } //end else
}

public static void copyFile (String source, String dest) throws Exception {

    //declare Files
    File sourceFile = null;
    File destFile = null;

    //declare stream variables
    FileInputStream sourceStream = null;
    FileOutputStream destStream = null;

    //declare buffering variables
    BufferedInputStream bufferedSource = null;
    BufferedOutputStream bufferedDest = null;

    try {
        //Create File objects for source and destination files
        sourceFile = new File (source);
        destFile = new File (dest);

        //Create file streams for the source and destination
        sourceStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
        destStream = new FileOutputStream(destFile);

        //Buffer the file streams with a buffer size of 8k
        bufferedSource = new BufferedInputStream(sourceStream,8182);
        bufferedDest = new BufferedOutputStream(destStream,8182);

        //Use an integer to transfer data between files
        int transfer;

        //Alert user as to what is happening
        System.out.println("Beginning file copy:");
        System.out.println("\tCopying " + source);
        System.out.println("\tTo      " + dest);

        //Read a byte while checking for End of File (EOF)
        while ((transfer = bufferedSource.read()) !=-1){

        //Write a byte
        bufferedDest.write(transfer);
    }//end while

    }//end try

    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("An unexpected I/O error occurred.");
    }//end catch

    finally {
        //close file streams
        if (bufferedSource !=null)
            bufferedSource.close();

        if (bufferedDest !=null)
            bufferedDest.close();

        System.out.println("Your files have been copied correctly and "
                + "closed.");
    }//end finally
}//end copyDir

}//end class
```

Comment: Is it right, that you get dirName and destName and then at the first call of isDirFile you make a dir destName + dirName? If in dirName is only a a name, from where the files should be copied?

Answer (score 0):

If you read through JavaDocs, you will see that `mkdir`...

> Creates the directory named by this abstract pathname.

This is a little obscure, but basically, it will only create the last level of the directory.  For example, if you have a path of `C:\this\is\a\long\path`, mkdir would only attempt to create the `path` directory at the end of `C:\this\is\a\long`, but if `C:\this\is\a\long` doesn't exist  it will fail.

Instead, if you use mkdirs

> Creates the directory named by this abstract pathname, including any
>   necessary but nonexistent parent directories. Note that if this
>   operation fails it may have succeeded in creating some of the
>   necessary parent directories.

I'd also be check the results of these methods, as they will indicate if the operation was successful or not

I think `entries = dirFile.listFiles();` looks wrong, you should be listing the files from the source directory, not the destination...